# Reverse DataFrame Column, But Maintain the Index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following

```
In [214]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4,8), data=[33,22,11,00])

In [215]: df
Out[215]: 
    0
4  33
5  22
6  11
7   0
```

I'd like to reverse the order of the first column, but maintain the index in its current order, so `df` will look like

```
4   0
5  11
6  22
7  33
```

I can't seem to find the right `reset_index`, `reindex`, etc to make this happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `iloc` and slice appropriately

```
df.iloc[::-1]

    0
7   0
6  11
5  22
4  33
```

---

In order to preserve the index

***use `iloc`***

```
df.iloc[:] = df.iloc[::-1].values
```

***use `numpy`***

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[::-1], df.index, df.columns)
```

---

Both yield

```
    0
4  33
5  22
6  11
7   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your index into a temporary variable and then reapply index.

```
idx = df.index.values
df.sort_values([0], inplace=True)
df.index = idx
```

Not as clever but easy to understand