# Flip DataFrame column order by keeping the Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse, flip

I have a similar question to this one: [Reverse DataFrame Column, But Maintain the Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774766/reverse-dataframe-column-but-maintain-the-index)

Reversing the rows works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df.iloc[:] = df.iloc[::-1].values
```

How can I reverse the columns to get this result

```
   0  1  2
0  3  2  1
1  6  5  4
2  9  8  7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy flip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) to reverse the columns :

```
pd.DataFrame(np.flip(df.to_numpy()))

    0   1   2
0   3   2   1
1   6   5   4
2   9   8   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the reverse to column by add `,`

```
df.iloc[:] = df.iloc[:,::-1].values
df
   0  1  2
0  3  2  1
1  6  5  4
2  9  8  7
```